# Python in HTML: Iterating over several lists by changing the name of a variable

Tags: python, html

I am quite new at this, so please excuse if the level of the question is low.

I am trying to go through 21 lesson-notes in the form of list-variables, getting the contents of each lesson-note, which each contains several sub-categories. These are to be displayed in a web-page through HTML.

The lesson-notes are named `lesson1`, `lesson2`,... `lesson21`

My code looks like this:

```
    {% for i in range(1, 22) %}

      {% for content in "lesson" + "str(i)" %}
        <div class="col-md-9 contents" id="{{content[0]}}">
         {{content[2] | safe}}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

I obviously know that what I am doing is not correct, but I decided to leave the `"lesson" + "str(i)"` in there, so that you can see what I am hoping to do. This is, of course, where I want the `lesson1`, `lesson2` etc.

So you can hopefully see what I am trying to do, but I don't know how to do it and can't find the answer anywhere. How do I make the second `for` loop run for `lesson1`, `lesson2` etc up until `lesson21`?

`content[2]` is the placeholder in the list for the content of that specific sub-category. Each lesson contains between 2 and 6 lists.

Additional info:

The first answer I received was good, but not so good for me, as my lists are already lists of lists.
i.e.

`lesson1 = [
            ['reference-titel', 'part-titel', """content"""],
            ['reference-titel2', 'part-titel2', """content"""],
            [......]
           ]`

And, I am building a drop-down menu above, which looks like this:

```
      `<div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
          The Web and Basic HTML
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {% for content in lesson1 %}
              <li><a href="#{{content[0]}}">{{content[1]}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>`
```

So if I put all the different sub-categories of all 21 lessons into one single, and very large, list of sub-categories, I wouldn't be able to make separate drop-down menus for them all, each with their own title.

Or would I? And if so, how would I do this?

Comment: @hege_hegedus: Thank you for the answer. But since my lists are already lists of lists, this solution is problematic for me.

Comment: You can still have list of lists of lists, and is still more readable. By the way, what templating engine do you use?

Comment: You can accept an answer you like the most by clicking on the tick sign, so the question gets closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list instead of separate variables. So instead of:

```
lession1 = [category1, category2, ...]
lession2 = [category10, category11, ...]
```

Use:

```
lessons = [
    [category1, category2, ...],
    [category10, category11, ...]
]
```

So you can iterate over all the lessions in your template:

```
{% for lesson in lessons %}

  {% for content in lesson %}
    <div class="col-md-9 contents" id="{{content[0]}}">
     {{content[2] | safe}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have variables `x1,x2,x3,x4,...,x20` it is always better and possible to have a list instead of separate variables.

```
lessons = [
    [
        ['reference-titel', 'part-titel', """content"""],
        ['reference-titel2', 'part-titel2', """content"""],
        [...]
    ],
    [
        ['reference-tite10', 'part-tite100', """content"""],
        ['reference-titel11', 'part-tite200', """content"""],
        [...]
    ]
]

template = `{% for lesson in lessons %}
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
          The Web and Basic HTML
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {% for content in lesson %}
              <li><a href="#{{content[0]}}">{{content[1]}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}`
```

For readability you can define a class instead the innermost arrays:

```
class Drop:
    def __init__(self, reference, part, content):
        self.reference = reference
        self.part = part
        self.content = content

lessons = [
    [
        Drop('reference-titel', 'part-titel', """content"""),
        Drop('reference-titel2', 'part-titel2', """content"""),
        Drop(...)
    ],
    [
        Drop('reference-tite10', 'part-tite100', """content"""),
        Drop('reference-titel11', 'part-tite200', """content""")
    ]
]

template = `{% for lesson in lessons %}
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
          The Web and Basic HTML
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {% for content in lesson %}
              <li><a href="#{{content.reference}}">{{content.part}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: Thank you. But this, although helpful, is not enough for me. Or at least I think not. I have added more info to my question. Do you think you could comment on that? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the time you've used for it! I finally ended up creating one big list named `lesson`, like you sugested and then running two for loops within each other, like this: `{% for items in lesson %}

          {% for content in items %}
            <div class="col-md-9 contents" id="{{content[0]}}">
             {{content[2] | safe}}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

@hege_hegedus pointed me in the correct direction. I put all my different variables into one big list, like:

`lesson = [
    [
        ['reference-titel', 'part-titel', """content"""],
        ['reference-titel2', 'part-titel2', """content"""],
        [...]
    ],
    [
        ['reference-tite10', 'part-tite100', """content"""],
        ['reference-titel11', 'part-tite200', """content"""],
        [...]
    ]
]`

Then I used two for loops within each other like:

`{% for items in lesson %}
    {% for content in items %}
      <div class="col-md-9 contents" id="{{content[0]}}">
        {{content[2] | safe}}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}`

This gave me what I wanted.